# Optimizing a parsing php script

Tags: php, performance

The script is intended to return an array with texts containing specific words in English and the equivalent texts in Polish from EUR-Lex - a website with EU documents.

The script downloads the page which address is specified by the passed variable. Then the page

http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1436957054496&text=%22event%20of%20default%22&scope=EURLEX&type=quick&lang=en

is parsed using regular expressions for the document codes. These codes are then used to access another page:

http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-PL/TXT/?qid=1436957054496&uri=CELEX:32013R0575&from=EN

The page above is then parsed for elements contained within  tags, which, if their content contains words from the variable (checked with a regular expression), are saved in an array.

For variables containing 1-2 words the script works fairly well; not so well for more. I got complaints from my free hosting provider (hostinger.in) that the script uses too much resources. I have other scripts run before that script, but not simultanously, so I don't if they contribute to the problem.

I'm new to programming so you can assume I made all the errors I could. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
//test variables
//$var1 = 'board_of_directors';
//$var1 = 'affidavit';
$var1 = 'event_of_default';
$var1 = explode("_", $var1);
$words = implode(" ",$var1);
if (count($var1) >= 2) {
    $var1 = implode("%20",$var1);
} else {
    $var1 = implode("%",$var1);
}
$var1 = "\""."$var1"."\"";
$html = file_get_contents("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1&text=$var1&scope=EURLEX&type=quick&lang=en");
preg_match_all('/CELEX:(\w+)&/si', $html, $matches2);
$result = array_unique($matches2[1]);
$result2 = file_get_contents("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-PL/TXT/?uri=CELEX:$result[0]&from=EN");
$dom = new domDocument; 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($result2); 
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$return_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length - 1; $i++) {
    $text1 = $items->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
    if (preg_match('/' . $words . '/i', $text1)) {
        $text2 = $items->item($i)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent;
        array_push($return_array, $text1);
        array_push($return_array, $text2);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return_array);

?>
```

Comment: You can start by fixing the syntax error.

Comment: This question should be posted over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/